# Return an error if the parameters are empty

Tags: maxima

I have function for example:

`bagman(a, b) := (c:length(a), b+c)`

And I would like to check parameter 'a' whether is empty. If it is empty this return information for example:

```
print("Parameter a is empty")
```

I tried this:

```
bagman(a, b) := (if length(a) = 0 then return(print("anything")), c:length(a), b+c)
```

but not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` doesn't have the same effect in Maxima as it does in other languages.

How about this:

```
bagman(a, b) :=
  if length(a) = 0
    then print("anything")
    else (c:length(a), b+c);
```

Note that I put the normal operation stuff `(c:length(a), b+c)` into the `else` so it doesn't get evaluated when `length(a) = 0`.